# How to automate change private key of SSH and VPN every 3 hours?

Tags: ssh, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, ansible, cisco-router

I Would like to change private key of SSH in Linux and Cisco device, and also VPN in every 3 hours.

Can someone suggest me how to achieve it?

Comment: Private key of the user (authorized key) or of the device itself (hostkey)? And... what's the point of changing it so often?

Comment: Because afraid of supercomputer or ISP can decrypt. If not often , it also a common practice to change every few months in security field.

Comment: Then you're looking at the completely wrong kind of keys. (And severely underestimating the current strength of modern algorithms such as DH and AES.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). SSHv2, as well as modern TLS and IPsec configurations, **already implement it** by using [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to generate a new encryption key for every connection. In most cases, you don't need to do anything extra.

In particular, changing the SSH client's or server's private key won't help all – they *are not used* for encryption to begin with. The only purpose of these keys is to make a digital signature for authentication purposes.

However, there are still some parameters you could check and adjust:

- In TLSv1.2-based services, make sure the allowed ciphersuites use "DHE"/"ECDHE" – as in "ephemeral DH". Depending on your clients, it might be possible to disable traditional DHE and keep only ECDHE ciphersuites. (If not, then at least generate a new "DH parameters" file for every service instead of using the default file).

  For more up-to-date information, search for [TLS deployment best practices](https://www.google.com/search?q=tls+deployment+best+practices).
- In SSHv2, look through the enabled key exchange algorithms (KexAlgorithms). You might want to consider disabling all "diffie-hellman-*" modes (or if you're using OpenSSH, at least regenerating the `/etc/ssh/moduli` file).

Additionally, SSHv2 and IPsec support automatically restarting the key exchange and switch to a new encryption key after a certain time interval and/or after a large amount of data has been transferred. In OpenSSH (client or server) you can enable periodic rekeying by setting the `RekeyLimit` option. In IPsec rekeying is usually enforced through the security association "lifetime" settings.

Comment: What is the minimum rekey lifetime can be set? seconds or minutes? if I set rekey , will large amount of data to rekey still effect?

Comment: Can linux VPN set rekey?

Comment: What kind of VPN? There are _dozens_ of VPN protocols. IPsec (IKE) supports rekeying; for everything else, refer to the vendor's documentation.

Comment: Why TLS is used but ISP or police or military still can see VPN ? is it that they get certificate at the beginning?

Comment: Probably. But even without it, the handshake has a well-defined and recognizable format. TLS only protects the data transferred through it, but it doesn't try to disguise the fact itself that TLS is being used. The same goes for most VPN types. It's usually not a security problem (unless you're trying to protect against e.g. GFW of China).

Comment: What do GFW do that can sniff VPN? real time decrypt? why differ Hellman failed to protect against GFW? why normal network user know what I do in bank and browse what? how do they know? How can I know theirs?

Comment: Generally you can't. Where did you get the idea that they know what you do?

Comment: Hear talking then got a feeling. even if I put off short sighted glasses and disable WiFi and not connect cable and Ethernet. I guess I need to buy latitude dell encrypted hard disk notebook. from gmail , outlook, even some apps, to notebook and bank. Always feel a Nobel prized Level sniffer know what I do.